# How to center the three js canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, three.js

I have this really weird (possibly intended?) bug with my three js canvas.
I want to have it not fill the complete page and center the canvas inside a div.

As you can see in the code below, the canvas is inside the div. I even added some test headings to make sure I'm not going crazy here, but the canvas seems to move itself outside the div and I have no idea how to fix this.

```
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>My first three.js app</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
        #test {
            width: 100px;
            height:100px;
            margin: 0px auto;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css" src="css/main.css"></style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">
        <h1>test1</h1>
        <canvas id="canvasID"></canvas>
        <h2>test2</h2>
    </div>  
    <script src="https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="three.js-master/build/three.js"></script>
    <script>
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasID");
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvas });

        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth*0.9, window.innerHeight*0.9 );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add( cube );

        camera.position.z = 5;
        function render() {
            requestAnimationFrame( render );
            cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
            cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
        render();

        if (Detector.webgl) {
            init();
            animate();
        } else {
            var warning = Detector.getWebGLErrorMessage();
            document.getElementById('container').appendChild(warning);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

[image][image]

As you can see, the canvas has "magically" moved outside of its parent div

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code you have this line `document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );` which appends the canvas to the end of the `<body>` tag. So you are adding the canvas outside of your required div.

You can add your canvas inside that div with a simple javascript selector like:
`document.getElementById('test').appendChild( renderer.domElement );`

or

`document.querySelector('#test').appendChild( renderer.domElement );`

That way you are adding the renderer **inside** the div with the `id="test"`. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks! I feel like such an idiot right now. Instead of using appendchild I just removed the incorrect line as the canvas is already positioned correctly in my HTML.